# MySQL INNER JOIN with GROUP BY and COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, inner-join

I've never been able to get my head around INNER JOINs (or any other JOIN types for that matter) so I'm struggling to work out how to use it in my specific situation.  In fact, I'm not even sure if it's what I need.  I've looked at other examples and read tutorials but my brain just doesn't seem to work the way needed to truly get it (or it doesn't function at all).

Here's the scenario:

I have two tables -

1. phone_numbers - this table has a list of phone numbers that
   belong to lots of different customers.  A single customer can have
   multiple numbers.  For simplicity's sake, we'll say the fields are
   'number_id', 'customer_id', 'phone_number'.
2. call_history - this table has a record of every single call that one of these
   numbers in the first table could have had.  There's a record for
   every individual call going back years.  Again, for simplicity,
   we'll say the relevant fields are customer_id, phone_number,
   call_start_time.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to find all of the numbers that belong to a particular customer_id in the phone numbers table and use that information to search through the call_history table and find the number of calls each phone number has received, and group that by the number of calls for each number, preferably also showing zeros where a number hasn't received any calls at all.

The reason the zero calls is important is because that's the data I'm interested in.  Otherwise, I could just get all the information out of the call_history table.  But what I'm trying to achieve is find the numbers with no activity.

All I've been able to accomplish is run one query to get all of the numbers belonging to one customer:

```
SELECT customer_id, phone_number FROM phone_numbers WHERE customer_id = Y;
```

Then run a second query to get all phone calls for that customer_id for a set duration:

```
SELECT customer_id, phone_number, COUNT(*) FROM call_history WHERE customer_id = Y and call_start_time >= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) GROUP BY phone_number;
```

I've then had to use the data returned from both queries and use a VLOOKUP function in Excel to match number of calls for each individual number from the second query to the list of all numbers from the first query, thus leaving blanks in my "all numbers" table and identifying those numbers that had no calls for that time period.

I'm hoping there's some way to do all of this with a single query and return a table of results, listing the zero number of calls with it and eliminate the whole manual Excel bit as it's not overly efficient and prone to human error.

Comment: What is the type of call_start_time field?

Comment: Please show what parts you can do. Please give a [mre]. Ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. And it's time to follow an introductory textbook on SQL. PS x inner join y on c returns every row that is an x row pasted to a y row that satisfies c. Ie x cross join y where c. So, which of the x cross join y rows do you want? Etc. Ask re where you are 1st stuck.

Comment: I bet once you've understand how all the `JOIN` functions, it will be very easy to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Without at least a workable example from you, it's not easy to re-create your situation. Anyway, `INNER JOIN` might not return the result as how you expected. In my short time with MySQL, I mainly use 2 types of `JOIN`; one is already mentioned and the other is `LEFT JOIN`. From what I can understand in your question, what you want to achieve can be done by using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. I may not be the best person to explain this to you but this is how I understand it:

INNER JOIN - only return anything that match in ON clause between two (or more) tables.

LEFT JOIN - will return everything from the table on the left side of the join and return NULL if ON get no match in the table on the right side of the join .. unless you specify some WHERE condition from something on the right table.

Now, here is my query suggestion and hopefully it'll be useful for you:

```
SELECT A.customer_id, A.phone_number, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN call_start_time >= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total 
FROM phone_numbers A 
LEFT JOIN call_history B
ON A.customer_id=B.customer_id 
GROUP BY A.customer_id,A.phone_number;
```

What I did here is I `LEFT JOIN` phone_numbers table with call_history on customer_id and I re-position the `WHERE  call_start_time >= ..` condition into a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` since putting it at `WHERE` will turn this into a normal join or inner join instead.

Here is an example fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hriFWqVy5RGbnsdj8i3aVG/1

Comment: Thanks for this info.  It's very close, however I added an extra number for customer 'Y' in your fiddle with no call_history records for that number and I expected that to show in the result with '0' in the Total column.  Instead it showed a '3' which is the number of calls the other number had in that timeframe.  I've updated the fiddle if you want to see what I mean.  In the meantime, I'll keep playing.

Comment: I worked out (through mostly guesswork) what I needed to change with this to get what I want.  Instead of LEFT JOIN call_history B ON A.customer_id=B.customer_id, I needed LEFT JOIN call_history B ON A.phone_number=B.phone_number.  I now get zeros where I should get zeros.  Also added a WHERE to filter out only the customer_id I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: I didn't foresee the possibility of having similar customer_id with different number but I'm glad you managed to work it out @MarkJohnson . You could answer your question with your final query and the updated fiddle :)

Answer (score -1):

For Inner join  You should have to do like this way..

SELECT customer_id,phone_number FROM phone_numbers as pn,call_history as ch where pn.customer_id = ch.customer_id and call_start_time >= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) GROUP BY phone_number;

Just add table name whatever you want to join and add condition

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above is a valid solution.